# How to use Apollo-Gateway with swagger-to-graphql tool?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, apollo-gateway

I'm using Swagger Petstore via `swagger-to-graphql` npm module and able to run the GraphQL Playground for it.

```
graphQLSchema('./swagger.json', 'http://petstore.swagger.io/v2', {
  Authorization: 'Basic YWRkOmJhc2ljQXV0aA=='
}).then(schema => {
  const app = express();
  app.use('/', graphqlHTTP(() => {
    return {
      schema,
      graphiql: true
    };
  }));
  app.listen(4001, 'localhost', () => {
    console.info('http://localhost:4001/');
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

However, when I tried to feed the service to Apollo Gateway, it throws `Error: Apollo Server requires either an existing schema or typeDefs`

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    { name: 'pet', url: 'http://localhost:4001' }
  ],
});
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,

  // Currently, subscriptions are enabled by default with Apollo Server, however,
  // subscriptions are not compatible with the gateway.  We hope to resolve this
  // limitation in future versions of Apollo Server.  Please reach out to us on
  // https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-server if this is critical to your adoption!
  subscriptions: false,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/implementing/#defining-a-federated-service):

> Converting an existing schema into a federated service is the first step in building a federated graph. To do this, we'll use the buildFederatedSchema() function from the  @apollo/federation package.

You cannot provide just any existing service to the gateway -- the service must meet the [federation spec](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/federation-spec). The only way to currently do that is to use `buildFederatedSchema` to create the service's schema. At this time, `buildFederatedSchema` [does not accept existing schemas](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/3013) so federation is not compatible with any other tools that generate a schema for you. Hopefully that feature will be added in the near future.